# Alternatives to lichdom for a GOO warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, warlock

I play a Great Old One Warlock - his patron is a living demiplane of knowledge that manifests as an endless dark library with something always lurking just out of sight.

He serves his patron by constantly collecting and sending it any scraps of magical, forbidden, or simply novel information he can find, so my DM hasn't really used the patron as a plot thread for anything yet, but I've been thinking about what my characters ultimate goal would be re: the patron, and I think he'd want to eventually be elevated to a favoured servant of the patron, something akin to a lich.

However, the lich doesn't feel Lovecraft-y enough, at least as it's commonly described. A Mind Flayer might be more appropriate (considering the GOOlock's telepathic features) but that still feels kind of wrong also.

Are there any other Far Realm/extradimensional/Lovecraftesque equivalents I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! This sort of ideas-generating question isn't really a good fit for our site. It might be possible to rephrase it to something along the lines of 'what published creatures fit X criteria', but I'm not quite sure. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!